# How to change python version in apache toree pyspark notebook?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, apache-toree

I am running Apache Toree for Pyspark Notebook. I had anaconda 3.5 and jupyter hub installed on unix machines. When I am invoking pyspark from Jupyter notebook it's starting with Python 2.7 instead of Anaconda 3.5.

Requesting your help in changing python version.

Please see I had already tried changing python version via os.environ but it didn't worked.

[image]

Comment: How did you install Toree? You specify the Python environment when you set it up

Comment: first installed via pip. It got installed in anaconda. Then jupyter toree install.

Comment: Thank You. Installed a new kernel with spark home and python path.  jupyter toree install --spark_home="spark_path" --kernel_name=tanveer_kernel1 --interpreters=PySpark,SQL  --python="python_path"

Answer (score 0):

Followed Below steps for configuring Toree with Python-3:

1. Installed a new kernel with spark home and python path.

   jupyter toree install --spark_home="spark_path" --kernel_name=tanveer_kernel1 --interpreters=PySpark,SQL --python="python_path"

   2. After doing above there were issues with Driver Python version and Executor Python version. Corrected Python Version in spark-env.sh by adding

   export PYSPARK_PYTHON="/usr/lib/anaconda3/bin/python"
   export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="/usr/lib/anaconda3/bin/python"

   3. Restarted spark services.